# Simulate "Ok" pressed in a confirm message?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to simulate the Enter key on a confirm box?

The type of box created by `confirm("Press a button!");`

Comment: What do you mean by "simulate" ? What is the expected behavior ?

Comment: `confirm` is a blocking call, meaning your JS will stop executing while it's open.  If you're hoping to "click" it from JS, you're not able to.  If you don't mean via JS, please clarify your question.

Comment: @Ephi I think he means, can we programmatically confirm a confirm box... Though this raises the question why?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Unit testing, perhaps? (in which case a redesign of the code will be required to make it testable).

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ok that could make sense

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From JavaScript, running within the page, not really.

The standard browser `confirm` dialog is modal and blocking. Absolutely no JS will run in the page while it is sitting there.

The closest you could come would be to override the function entirely.

```js
function yes() {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("You said yes! "));
}

function sure() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    yes();
  }
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", sure);

window.confirm = function myConfirm() {
  return true;
}
```

```html
<button>Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling the answer was that kind. Sadly I can't change it since I run an overlay.